# UITableViewCell get UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uiapplication

I have got an `UITableViewCell` and I want to call a void in a `ViewController` of the `UITabBar` in it. Is that possible using `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`? If yes, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty vague, the answer is yes, it is possible to do such a thing. You just need to design your classes in such a way to make it possible.

A number of ways to approach it

1. Create a method on `ViewController`'s interface that `UITableViewCell` can call
2. Use the delegate pattern
3. Post a notification and observer the notification in `ViewController`

With that said, this sounds weird to me, why would your UITableViewCell act on a UITabBar? The interaction "feels" strange. Usually touching a cell in a table does not change the tab that the user is on, it could be fairly confusing. If that is not what you're doing, then why is this method in the ViewController that controls the UITabBar? You may need to separate your concerns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The point is that I do not want to change the Tab. It will just call a void of an UITabBars tabs ViewController!

Comment: What does that void method do?

Comment: It adds a String to an Array and reloads the included TableView, which will cause starting an async download.

Comment: Sounds like a method that is a separate concern from the UITabBar's class. I'd abstract the method into a different class that you can call in a more sensible.

Comment: Well, I now found a way doing it using a custom [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate! I think I used to many subclasses. Thanks anyway!